# How does work position sticky relative window?

Tags: html, css

Lets suppose we have window with horizontal scroll.

There is another block on the page. If set it `position: relative` and set `top: 20px` does it mean that `20px` from top of window in visible area or including scroll?

Comment: `position: relative` is not sticky to window. It will move `20px` from `top` if you add `(top: 20px)` depending up on its placement in the `DOM`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is demo of your question. Not sure if this answers your question, feel free to edit.

https://jsfiddle.net/joshmoto/zbc12ayu/1/

```css
@import "https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css";

.scroll-x {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  height: 400px;
  border: 2px dotted #e83e8c;
}

.top-block {
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
  height: 40px;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  color: #ffffff;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}

.scolling-content {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, orange, yellow, green, cyan, blue, violet);
  width: 2560px;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container mt-3">

  <h4 class="mt-3 mb-3">Scroll Horizontal</h4>

  <div class="scroll-x">
  
    <div class="top-block"><code>position: relative; top: 20px;</code></div>
    <div class="scolling-content"></div>
    
  </div>

</div>
```